# Why I cannot boot to Ubuntu 20.04 after Windows 10 installation?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I had my laptop dual boot with Win 7 and Ubuntu 18.04 and after being in repair shop for a while, I noticed that win 7 was broken so I installed win 10. But after installing win 10 I can't boot to Ubuntu anymore.

I was very cautious during win 10 installation so I'm sure I didn't deleted any Ubuntu partition or any grub bootloader. Even if this is the case win 10 won't let me boot from my USB which has Ubuntu 20.04 in it. Every time I choose to boot from USB I can't and Win10 logo appears. I also changed BIOS settings from `Legacy` to `UEFI Hybrid (with CSM)` or even to `UEFI` but it says that no image was found.

And also in the boot options my USB which has my Ubuntu is not showing(in  `UEFI Hybrid (with CSM)` and `UEFI`) . I see just `boot from EFI` and when I hit enter I see the `/` but if I hit enter again it won't do anything. I have disabled also `Fast Boot` on windows and `BIOS` too. I know that there are many questions but none of them is helping me since the BIOS menu is different. My laptop is `HP ProBook 6570b`.

Best Regards guys.

edit: My question is also different because the problem originated from making the USB bootable and didn't had any configuration issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Windows 10 is installed in UEFI mode (non CSM) with GPT partitioning. (And your Ubuntu was installed in UEFI (with CSM). They are both different and that's why not working side by side.

1. Change your boot settings from **BIOS** to **UEFI Only** (Non CSM).
2. Make a bootable USB using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie)

   - Choose partitioning scheme to **GPT**
   - Choose boot mode to **UEFI Only** (Non CSM)
3. Boot from USB
4. Install Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem :D :D :D :D

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Reboot,
Hit F10 or other to access BIOS settings,
Select "Legacy Support",
Set legacy support to "enabled",
Save changes and exit,
Reboot.

Now each time you boot you should be offered the option to continue with Windows or select Linux/Ubuntu...